# How to share docker images between the jobs in github actions

Tags: github-actions

I recently moved to GitHub action. Trying to make this work for days but could find a proper solution.

[image]

- In `JOB1` I am building `Image A` and using `Image A` as a base Image to build `Image B`.
- Now `Image B` will act as a base image to build `Image C` in JOB2 and `Image D` in Job3.

I have already tried these 2 solutions but they didn't work.

1. https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/issues/225#issuecomment-727639184
2. https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/build-images-on-github-actions-with-docker-layer-caching

Some of the errors I am getting when tried the above solutions:

```
Error: buildx failed with: error: failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

Comment: Can you please share your GitHub Actions workflow files?

Comment: I am not sure if that the optimize way but I am pushing image B into ECR and then pulling it on Image C and D job